# Can't connect Google Service Account with Kubernetes Service Account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, devops, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud, google-cloud-iam

I've been following [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity?cloudshell=true#gcloud_3) to set up a Kubernetes Cluster on GCP with Workload Identity, and I'm completely stuck with service account permissions.

```
gcloud container clusters create test-cluster \
    --region=europe-west1 \
    --workload-pool=my-project.svc.id.goog

gcloud container clusters get-credentials test-cluster \
    --region=europe-west1

kubectl create namespace test-kns

kubectl create serviceaccount test-ksa \
    --namespace test-kns

gcloud iam service-accounts create test-gsa \
    --project=my-project

gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding my-project \
    --member "serviceAccount:test-gsa@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com" \
    --role "roles/composer.worker"

gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding test-gsa@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
    --role roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser \
    --member "serviceAccount:my-project.svc.id.goog[test-kns/test-ksa]"

kubectl annotate serviceaccount test-ksa \
    --namespace test-kns \
    iam.gke.io/gcp-service-account=test-gsa@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com

kubectl auth can-i list pods --all-namespaces --as "system:serviceaccount:test-kns:test-ksa"
[no]

gcloud config set auth/impersonate_service_account test-gsa@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com

gcloud container clusters get-credentials test-cluster --location europe-west1

kubectl auth can-i list pods --all-namespaces
[yes]
```

I think I've got all the steps in (a few are optional when Autopilot is enabled, which it is), but when I come to test the permissions with `kubectl`, I'm always told `no`. Impersonating the Google Service Account directly results in a `yes`.

The email annotation is present:

```
kubectl describe serviceaccount -n test-kns test-ksa                                        
Name:                test-ksa
Namespace:           test-kns
Labels:              <none>
Annotations:         iam.gke.io/gcp-service-account: test-gsa@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
Image pull secrets:  <none>
Mountable secrets:   <none>
Tokens:              <none>
Events:              <none>
```

Testing the email annotation in a pod as per the documentation is also fine:

```
root@workload-identity-test:/# curl -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google" http://169.254.169.254/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/email
test-gsa@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

Does anybody know what's missing between my GSA and KSA?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes synchronization delays between Google Cloud IAM and Kubernetes. Make sure that your service account **'test_gsa'**  is correctly annotated with Kubernetes Service Account **'test-ksa'** propagation may take some time to take effect. Additionally, add a sleep command to allow some time for annotations to propagate

Comment: Do you mean the KSA is annotated with the GSA email address, or the other way around?

Comment: Also unfortunately this was all set up >24hrs ago so I'd hope propagation is complete by now :)